# Hough Transform on arrays of coordinates(Stock prices)

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, hough-transform

I want to apply Hough Transform on stock prices (array of numbers).
I read `OpenCV` and `scikit-image` docs and examples ,but got nothing how to apply the transformation to the arrays of numbers instead of images.

I created 2D array from data. First dimension is X(simply index of data) and second dimension is close prices.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pywt as wt 
from skimage.transform import (hough_line, hough_line_peaks,probabilistic_hough_line)
from matplotlib import cm

path = "22-31May-100Tick.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(path)
y = df.Close.values
x = np.arange(0,len(y),1)
data = []
for i in x:
    a = [i,y[i]]
    data.append(a)

data = np.array(data)
```

How is it possible to apply the transformation with `OpenCV` or `sickit-image`?

Thank you

Comment: Please post an example image. I do not understand why you would do Hough line transform on such data/image

Comment: I want to do something like described in this papar http://sciencestudiespublication.com/uploads/128.pdf

Thank you so much @fmw42

Comment: I could be wrong, but I do not see that as a typical application of hough line detection that will produce what you want for such scattered data in that reference. You will get way too many line segments that likely will not give you a good trend. But I have not read that reference very carefully. Just my initial reaction. You will have to add your own filtering, since that is not part of the usual Hough transform, that I know. He does not seem to describe the filtering methods for extracting the one trend line desired.

Comment: @fmw42  Your are completely right about it, but I decided to filter the noise by using Wavelets and do some research about this approach. I just couldn't understand how to input these price data to the Hough Transform.
Thank you so much